# How To Turn off Stored Procedure Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL Server 2008 R2. Running a stored procedure via a cursor-controlled loop from the SS Management Studio. (below). After 3,000 of 9,000 loops I receive an out of memory error. I believe this is related only to SS Mgmt Studio. So how do I shut off the output of both the calling routine (below) and the invoked SPROC? I am open to another approach to invoke the SPROC (EXECUTE POPULATE_EMA @sym_in, 20,50,100,12,26, @mink_in, @maxk_in;)

```
DELETE FROM TA_HISTORY

DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT symbol, MinDSeqKey, MaxDSeqKey
   FROM STOCK_VITALS;

OPEN tables_cursor;

DECLARE @sym_in NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @mink_in bigint;
DECLARE @maxk_in bigint;

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @sym_in, @mink_in, @maxk_in;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN;
    --PRINT 'Now Processing. ' + @sym_in;
   EXECUTE POPULATE_EMA @sym_in, 20,50,100,12,26, @mink_in, @maxk_in;

   INSERT INTO TA_HISTORY(SYMBOL, DSEQKEY, EMA20, EMA50, EMA100, EMA12, EMA26)
   SELECT @sym_in, DSEQKEY, EMA1, EMA2,EMA3,EMA4,EMA5
   FROM temp_ema_data
   WHERE @maxk_in - @mink_in > 49

   FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @sym_in, @mink_in, @maxk_in;
END;

CLOSE tables_cursor;

DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;
```

** EDIT 5/18 - HERE IS THE SPROC - I NEED THE SPROC TO OPERATE ON 9,000+ ROWS IN ANOTHER TABLE.

```
BEGIN

DROP TABLE temp_ema_data

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_ema_data](
    [n] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dseqkey] [bigint] NULL,
    [close_price] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ema1] [decimal](8, 4) NULL,
    [ema2] [decimal](8, 4) NULL,
    [ema3] [decimal](8, 4) NULL,
    [ema4] [decimal](8, 4) NULL,
    [ema5] [decimal](8, 4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into temp_ema_data (dseqkey, close_price)
select dseqkey,prclose
from STOCK_HIST
where Symbol = @Symbol and dseqkey > @MinKey 
order by dseqkey asc

--declare variables needed
declare @K1 decimal(4,4), @K2 decimal(4,4), @K3 decimal(4,4), @K4 decimal(4,4)
, @K5 decimal(4,4)
declare @prev_ema_1 decimal(8,4), @prev_ema_2 decimal(8,4), @prev_ema_3 decimal(8,4)
, @prev_ema_4 decimal(8,4), @prev_ema_5 decimal(8,4),@initial_sma_1 decimal(8,4)
, @initial_sma_2 decimal(8,4), @initial_sma_3 decimal(8,2), @initial_sma_4 decimal(8,4)
, @initial_sma_5 decimal(8,4)
declare @anchor int

    set @K1 = 2/(1 + @ema_1_intervals + .000)
    set @K2 = 2/(1 + @ema_2_intervals + .000)
    set @K3 = 2/(1 + @ema_3_intervals + .000)
    set @K4 = 2/(1 + @ema_4_intervals + .000)
    set @K5 = 2/(1 + @ema_5_intervals + .000)           

select  @initial_sma_1 = avg(case when n < @ema_1_intervals 
        then close_price else null end),    
        @initial_sma_2  = avg(case when n < @ema_2_intervals 
        then close_price else null end),
        @initial_sma_3  = avg(case when n < @ema_3_intervals 
        then close_price else null end),
        @initial_sma_4  = avg(case when n < @ema_4_intervals 
        then close_price else null end),
        @initial_sma_5  = avg(case when n < @ema_5_intervals 
        then close_price else null end)                     
from temp_ema_data
where n < @ema_1_intervals or n < @ema_2_intervals or 
      n < @ema_3_intervals or n < @ema_4_intervals or
      n < @ema_5_intervals

update t1 
    set @prev_ema_1 = case 
    when n < @ema_1_intervals then null         
    when n = @ema_1_intervals then t1.close_price * @K1 + @initial_sma_1 * (1-@K1)  
    when n > @ema_1_intervals then t1.close_price * @K1 + @prev_ema_1 * (1-@K1) 
    end,
    @prev_ema_2 = case when n < @ema_2_intervals then null          
    when n = @ema_2_intervals then t1.close_price * @K2 + @initial_sma_2 * (1-@K2)  
    when n > @ema_2_intervals then t1.close_price * @K2 + @prev_ema_2 * (1-@K2)         
    end, 
    @prev_ema_3 = case when n < @ema_3_intervals then null          
    when n = @ema_3_intervals then t1.close_price * @K3 + @initial_sma_3 * (1-@K3)  
    when n > @ema_3_intervals then t1.close_price * @K3 + @prev_ema_3 * (1-@K3)         
    end, 
    @prev_ema_4 = case when n < @ema_4_intervals then null          
    when n = @ema_4_intervals then t1.close_price * @K4 + @initial_sma_4 * (1-@K4)  
    when n > @ema_4_intervals then t1.close_price * @K4 + @prev_ema_4 * (1-@K4)         
    end, 
    @prev_ema_5 = case when n < @ema_5_intervals then null          
    when n = @ema_5_intervals then t1.close_price * @K5 + @initial_sma_5 * (1-@K5)  
    when n > @ema_5_intervals then t1.close_price * @K5 + @prev_ema_5 * (1-@K5)         
    end,            
    ema1 = @prev_ema_1, ema2 = @prev_ema_2, ema3 = @prev_ema_3, ema4 = @prev_ema_4,
    ema5 = @prev_ema_5, @anchor = n --anchor so that carryover works properly   
from temp_ema_data t1 with (TABLOCKX) OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

END
```

Comment: What does your stored proc 'populate_ema' do? If you do selects of any sort, it will output the result - unless the selects are getting inserted (like above). You cannot suppress output results if you did a 'select' - thats what 'select' does...

Comment: @M.R. - well, you can by reinserting the results into another table, if the sproc only returns one resultset

Comment: I can think of no conceivable reason why I would use a cursor for any insert. This is just poor coding. You should make the proc so that it accepts a table variable for input and does a set-based operation or you should NOT use the child proc at all and do a set-based insert inthe calling proc. The way this is written will always take too much time and will be the kind of thing that will kill your system performance. Fix it now.

Comment: @tao - thats what I said - you can suppress it only if you are inserting... otherwise a straightfoward select will output the results...

Comment: @M.R. fair enough, I (mis-)understood your comment to be stating the results of that proc call could not be captured/discarded from the context we have been provided (without changing the proc that is doing the select)

Comment: Editing for formatting once is my limit per question. :)   Can you format your code properly using the editor? Just highlight it and click on the braces button ({}). Alternatively, put four spaces in front of all of the lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can try under the menu item: Query->Query options...

On the tree select Results->Grid and Results->Text (whichever is applicable for you) there is a check box for "Discard results after execution". I haven't used it, but it sounds like it might do what you need.

**EDIT:** A quick test shows that this discards both query results as well as PRINT statement output. Also, a loop of 100 calls to a simple stored procedure went from taking several seconds (mostly time spent displaying the results) to pretty much an instant run time. I think this is what you're looking to find.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding the following to the top of you SPROC:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: What does the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS do for you? The NOCOUNT will get rid of row counts, but not actual results.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that cursor's are resource hogs, if cursors isn't a requirement, I'd suggest using sql server [table variables](http://odetocode.com/code/365.aspx) as an alternative.

Also look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableVariablesVSCursor.aspx) for conversion of cursor based procedure to a table variable based procedure.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mark Kram points out, `SET NOCOUNT ON` is one thing you need, to prevent output from the sproc you showed us.

For the called sproc `POPULATE_EMA`, there is no way for us to know what it outputs based on the details you've provided - are you getting resultsets returned to SSMS?

If you are getting one resultset returned (to the client) per call to `POPULATE_EMA`, you may be able to `INSERT INTO` a temp table, on the server-side, to avoid that table being sent to the client. This would look something like:

```
DELETE FROM TA_HISTORY

--This table would need to match the structure of POPULATE_EMA!
CREATE TABLE #TempResults (Column1 Int, Column2 Int) --, etc

DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT symbol, MinDSeqKey, MaxDSeqKey
   FROM STOCK_VITALS;

OPEN tables_cursor;

DECLARE @sym_in NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @mink_in bigint;
DECLARE @maxk_in bigint;

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @sym_in, @mink_in, @maxk_in;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN;
    --PRINT 'Now Processing. ' + @sym_in;
   INSERT INTO #TempResults
   EXECUTE POPULATE_EMA @sym_in, 20,50,100,12,26, @mink_in, @maxk_in;

   INSERT INTO TA_HISTORY(SYMBOL, DSEQKEY, EMA20, EMA50, EMA100, EMA12, EMA26)
   SELECT @sym_in, DSEQKEY, EMA1, EMA2,EMA3,EMA4,EMA5
   FROM temp_ema_data
   WHERE @maxk_in - @mink_in > 49

   FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @sym_in, @mink_in, @maxk_in;
END;

CLOSE tables_cursor;

DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;
```